# Read multiple text files simultaneously in Scala

Tags: scala, io, parallel-processing, text-files

Given a collection of filenames to be read and processed, namely for instance,

```
val inFilenames = (1 to 100).map(n => s"file$n.txt")
```

how to read all `100` text files simultaneously, so that

```
def processFile[A](inFilename: String, f: => A): Int
```

may be called up to `100` times in parallel?

Many Thanks

Comment: Assume that the underlying file-system and infra provides enough bandwidth, perhaps also multiple NFS mount points and duplication (e.g. via RAID'ing).

Comment: As long as the files are on the same file system it is probably better to read them in one after the other. Especially on a hard disk sequential access can be much faster. So I suggest using a for loop to read the files in and then in the loop create futures to process the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems something you can solve with `Future`s:

```
def processFile[A](inFilename: String, f: => A): Int = ???

def someFunction[A]: A = ???

val inFilenames = (1 to 100).map { n => s"file$n.txt" }

val futures: List[Future[Int]] = 
  inFilenames.map(file => Future(processFile(file, someFunction))).toList
```

This will create a `List` with 100 `Future`s. Futures start running as soon as they are declared, to retrieve the results you can add the `onCallback` method or block (not suggested) using `Await.result(futures)`, in a more compact form it would be:

```
inFilenames.map(file => Future(processFile(file, someFunction)).onComplete {
  case Success(res) => println(res)
  case Failure(e) => println("failure: " + e.getMessage)
})
```